# Как создать триггер для сравнение внесенных дат в таблицу и вывод результата в пустую колонку SQLITE?

Tags: sql, база-данных, sqlite3, триггер, compare

У меня есть таблица с `date_start` и `date_end`, также есть пустая колонка `result`, при внесении дат в таблицу мой триггер не работает:

```
SELECT CASE date_start 
WHEN NEW.date_end > NEW.date_start 
THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END result;
```

Помогите пожалуйста!

Как сделать такой триггер, чтобы сравнивал даты и записывал результат в отдельный столбец?